# Android API design: Int vs. Float precision

Tags: android

I'm just wondering why some parts of Android UI are represented with `Int` precision while some other parts are represented with `Float`.

Is there any pragmatic reasoning behind this?

Example of `Int` based Android API:

- `View.width`/`View.height`
- `View.top`/`View.bottom`/...

Example of `Float` based Android API:

- `View.x`/`View.y`
- `View.translateX`/`View.translateY`

I'm asking this, because I often find myself in a position, where I have to do the calculations with both `Int`s and `Float`s.

If I can position a `View` with `Int` precision (`View.top/bottom/etc.`), but later move it with `Float` precision (`View.translateX`), why don't just have all the attributes as `Float`s?

Comment: I think the only people who can answer you work for Google.  But I'd say the likely answer is intended purpose.  THe first two are about layout, and you have to layout to a physical pixel.  The second two are about animation.  You still have to layout to the nearest pixel, but keeping partial pixels so that you can accumulate them makes sense-  you may want to move at 3.5 pixels per frame, and you don't want to round that down to 3.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Floats for animation related attrs vs. Ints for static attrs.